# json_serializable enhanced enums not working. This requires the 'enhanced-enums' language feature to be enabled

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serialization

I'm using the latest version of all these packages.

```
dependencies
  json_annotation: ^4.5.0

dev_dependencies:
  json_serializable: ^6.2.0
  build_runner: ^2.1.10
```

I also found that `json_serializable: 6.1.5` [added support for enhanced enums](https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/pull/1111). But when I run `flutter pub build_runner build` on

```dart
@JsonEnum(fieldRename: FieldRename.snake)
enum Foo {
  helloWorld,
  bar;
}
```

I get this error:

> This builder requires Dart inputs without syntax errors.
> However, package:example/main.dart (or an existing part) contains the > following errors.
> main.dart:15:8: This requires the 'enhanced-enums' language feature to be enabled.

I also noticed that all these packages's `pubspec.yaml` are still not using the Dart SDK `2.17.0`. I manually changed them to `2.17.0`.

Comment: Have you find anything yet?

Comment: @KartikGarasia No, you can upvote [this issue](https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/1148).

Comment: Yes I did... I also came across [this](https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/1147)

Answer (score 2):

The only way that i found to run build-runner without errors was adding
`--enable-experiment=enhanced-enums`
to the build_runner command so the complete command should be
`flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs --enable-experiment=enhanced-enums`. **This is only a temporal fix to be able to run the build_runner without errors**